# How to push some HTML every 3 times to array for output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I want to output div every 3 times in for loop.

Output rendered not as HTML.

How can I resolve this?

```
render() {
    const squareItems = [];

    for (var i=0; i < 9; i++) {
        if ((i % 3) == 0){
            squareItems.push('<div class="row">');
        }
        squareItems.push(this.renderSquare(i));

        if ((i % 3) == 2){
            squareItems.push('</div>');
        }
    }

    return (
      <div>
        { squareItems }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I need result:

I tried to use JSX to push, but it needed to close any tag anyway.

```
<div class="row">
 <div>1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div>4</div>
 <div>5</div>
 <div>6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div>7</div>
 <div>8</div>
 <div>9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you are trying to put html then try using `dangerouslysetinnerhtml`, i see you are mixing both html and jsx(in `this.renderSquare(i-1)`). Try to have only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option (that I prefer for readability) is below.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {Array(3).fill().map((_, index) => (
        <div class="row">
          {this.renderSquare(index * 3)}
          {this.renderSquare(index * 3 + 1)}
          {this.renderSquare(index * 3 + 2)}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And if you wanted the number of rows/squares to be dynamic, you could use the following:

```
render() {
  const rowCount = 3;
  const squaresPerRow = 3;

  return (
    <div>
      {Array(rowCount).fill().map((_, rowIndex) => (
        <div class="row">
          {Array(squaresPerRow).fill().map((_, squareIndex) => (
            this.renderSquare(rowIndex * squaresPerRow + squareIndex)
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think nesting loops is easiest solution:

```
render() {
    const squareItems = [];

    for (var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        squareItems.push(<div class="row">
            {Array(3).map((_, j) => this.renderSquare(i * 3 + j))}
        </div>);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        { squareItems }
      </div>
    );
  }
```